# How to pass values to new UIViewController from UIButton of Child UICollectionViewCell in nested UICollectionViews in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

i have UICollectionViewController with custom UICollectionViewCell which contains child UICollectionView and custom childUICollectionViewCell.

- UICollectionViewController

  - UICollectionViewCell (parentCell)

    - UILable
    - UICollectionView

      - UICollectionViewCell(childCell)

        - UILable (valueLable)
        - UIButton (Submit)
      - UICollectionViewCell(childCell)

        - UILable (valueLable)
        - UIButton (Submit)

i want to send text of "valueLable" on click "Submit" button to new UIViewController.
Please help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a protocol `SubmissionDelegateProtocol` with a method `-(void) submitWithValue:(NSString*)text;`

Your UICollectionViewController implements (conforms to) the protocol. 
It is supposed to provide this methods for the childViews to call it.

On creating the collection views and further collection and its collection views you will have to pass down a -let's say- sumbmitDelegate property (or init parameter) that is holding a reference to the UICollectionViewController which implements the protocol.

```
id <SubmissionDelegateProtocol> submissionDelegate;
```

When you work with storyboards, then the method `prepareForSegue:` is the appropriate place for handing further information down to subsequent view controllers. But if both collection views use the same ViewContoller as their dataSource, as your tree suggests, then it should be even easier.

So that in the end each of the cells holds a (weak) reference to the view conotroller. 
Then, upon button is pressed action, you call the delegate method
[submissionDelegate submitWithValue:[valueLable text]];

That's for the delegation pattern.

Alternatively you could work with notifications.

Comment: Great.. it helped me :) .  By protocol method... Some how NSNotification is not worked in my case.

Comment: Technically you don't need that protocol, but it is a nice neat way to de-couple classes, that don't need to be coupled. It enables re-use too.

Answer (score 0):

Try `NSNotification Center`

In Child View Controller, postNotifictaion

and in `UIViewController` listen to the same notification.

You can also pass data using `NSNotificationCenter`.

```
- (void) submitButtonClicked
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"dataFromChildToParent"  object:nil userInfo: valueLable.text];
}
```

and In `UIViewController`s ViewDidLoad Method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadRegistrationNotification:) name:@"dataFromChildToParent" object:nil];
```

and Implement the selector

```
- (void) loadRegistrationNotification:(NSNotification *)noti {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"dataFromChildToParent" object:nil];

    NSString *valueLabelText = [noti userInfo];
    NSLog(@"Notification data %@", valueLabelText);
}
```

For Detailed Explanation about `NSNotificationCenter` see this [Tutorial](http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/using-nsnotificationcenter-with-example/)